# Compiling invalid objects using dbms_utility.compile schema in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

We have an Oracle stored procedure (`Package_1.Procedure_1`) that alters tables and indexes based on certain conditions. Once this is done all the other objects (packages, views etc..) that reference the table becomes invalid. Even though Oracle automatically compile invalid objects the next time it is used, a certain package remains invalid (`Package_2`).

This `Package_2` is not called directly during the next operation, instead as `Package_2.Procedure_1` is called inside `Package_1`.

I am using the below statement in `Package_1` to compile the invalid objects before proceeding with next operation:

```
execute immediate 'Exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(Schema_Name, false)';
```

Package compiles but I get an error:

> ORA-00900 Invalid SQL statement (for the above code) when executed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `EXEC` is a SQL*Plus command. It's not valid PL/SQL. In this case, you don't even need to use dynamic sql. Note also that altering tables etc. at runtime is not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using execute immediate for performing this activity. You can directly use the utility in your package. If you don't know the value for the schema name then you can pass variables to the utility.

```
DECLARE
  v_user VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  v_user := 'DUMMY_USER_NAME';
  DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA(v_user);
END;
```

The above code runs fine for me.

Comment: When "DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA" is used directly the code doesn't throw any errors. But i still see some packages and triggers in invalid state..

Comment: @Jeshma when you recompile those packages manually do they compile? Are there any errors in user_errors, all_errors or dba_errors related to those packages.

Comment: Compiling the packages manually (SQL Developer, Right Click Packages, 'Compile Invalid') works even though there are a few errors when in user_errors